# Server side technology for streaming to async webrequests

Tags: c#, asynchronous, streaming, webrequest

I need to write a C# application that will sit and run as a service on a windows server.

This application will be responsible for sending JSON snippets to connected clients.

Clients will be connecting using an Asynchronous WebRequest and I want to Gzip encode the payloads to reduce the size of the packets being sent down the wire to each connected client. The data being sent to each client will differ so I need to manage all the connections as well.

Once a client is connected, they will remain connected for as long as possible, so the server will be sending heartbeats every x number of seconds.

I have not done programming like this since my days back in uni and wondered what the best way of achieving this was?

Can I use Sockets and standard TCP/IP with the WebRequest connection method?

Comment: You may take a look at signal-r http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: Which .NET are you going to use? Core or 462?

Comment: the clients are currently in .net 4.5 so most likely need to be compatible

Comment: I am leaning towards using HttpListener, anyone see a problem with using this?

Comment: Checkout Grapevine. It will do all this for you easily, including the gzip, out of the box. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Grapevine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the HttpListener in the end.